# How to add Object to JSONObject without content been escaped

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object which can be serialized to JSON using Jackson. I want to add this object to a JSONObject and have the content serialized

```
JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
put("something", "value");
put("myThing", myThing);
mapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
String s = msg.toString();
```

but the result is

```
{"something":"value","myThing":"com.example.things"}
```

I have tried

```
put("myThing", mapper.valueToTree(myThing))
// and 
put("myThing", mapper.writeValueAsString(myThing))
```

however both of these result in the child object beening escaped

```
{"something":"value","myThing":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}
```

**How do I get what I really want ...**

```
{"something":"value","myThing":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Comment: please add your toString method

Comment: @hasan83 updated the first code block to show how I am getting the string

Answer (score 2):

Create an JSONObject for the myThing object.

Like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("foo", myThing.getFoo());
```

and add this to the main JSONObject:

```
JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
msg.put("something", "value");
msg.put("myThing", obj);
```

---

Another method is to use Annotations to mark the fields in a class which should be serialized and then generate the JSON Object via reflection.

[I have some classes on Github which you can use](https://github.com/Zelldon/Zell-Android-Util/tree/master/Zell-Android-Util/src/de/zell/android/util/json).

Example for usage:

```
public class MyClass {
 @JSONElement(name = "foo")
 private String field1;

 MyClass(String f) {
  this.field1 = f;
 }
 [...]
}

MyClass object = new MyClass("bar");
JSONObject json = JSONMarshaller.marshall(object);
```

The resulting JSON for this object is:

```
 {"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: Would prefer something closer to the first part of your answer but the child object been serialized is more complex than just {"foo":"bar"}. Given you have had to write your Marshaller in the past I guess it must not be built in to Jackson.

Comment: JAX-RS has also a built in marshaller which uses the XmlElement annoations. I have made my marshaller for android. See this tutorial for JAX-RS and marshalling http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

I had managed to mix up `org.json` and `com.fasterxml.jackson`.

```
ObjectNode msg = mapper.createObjectNode();
msg.put("something", "value");
msg.put("myThing", mapper.valueToTree(myThing));
String s = msg.toString();
```

This now gives the output I was expecting